# Change UUID encoding to base-32 in spring-data-rest HAL _links

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We recently began converting our controllers over to spring-data-rest repositories but in our system we must encode UUIDs in base-32.

We were able to solve this for the response content and the urls using the RepositoryRestConfigurer but the UUIDs still show in the standard format in the _links.

Current jackson mapper config:

```
@Override
public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService)
{
  conversionService.addConverter(String.class, UUID.class, new StringUuidConverter());
}

@Override public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper)
{
  SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
  module.addSerializer(UUID.class, new UUIDSerialiser());
  module.addDeserializer(UUID.class, new UUIDDeserialiser());

  objectMapper.registerModule(module);
}
```

Is there a similar way to change the _links?

Edit:
We have decided to enable support for dash separated uuids along with base32 in incoming requests. This is not a great solution however as it is confusing for clients that our _links are not base32 so we are still looking for a proper solution

Comment: If you change the representation of uuid in _link section, the client app may request a link with this base32 coded uuid. Is your backend app ready to serve this link without implicit decoding?

Comment: Yes it is expecting all uuids to be encoded in base32. So currently the links all fail with 404

Answer (score 1):

By default, the liveness and readiness probe paths use Spring Boot 2.x+ actuator endpoints. To use Spring Boot 1.x actuator endpoint paths, you must adjust the liveness and readiness values, as the following example shows (replace  with the name of your application):

```
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.livenessProbePath=/health
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.readinessProbePath=/info
```

To automatically set both liveness and readiness endpoints on a per-application basis to the default Spring Boot 1.x paths, you can set the following property:

```
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.bootMajorVersion=1
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, how would this change the uuid encoding?